# docker Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: linux, service, docker, systemd

i spend more time to learn many posts here and out, but i don't find the solution, so i came here to ask :

i wanna run docker on manjaro linux OS (archlinux like)

```
uname -a
Linux boblinux-pc 4.1.15-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 15 07:48:44 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

after installing docker, i wanna start it :

```
sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.socket failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

so i have this problem, so i did :

```
systemctl cat docker
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupf
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/lxc.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -e lxc
....
```

and i did :

```
systemctl cat docker.socket
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API
PartOf=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

ok so the installation seemms ok , so error message says me to execute this :

```
systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─lxc.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since jeu. 2016-01-07 13:34:44 CET; 2min 0s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1970 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -e lxc (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1970 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.516598..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.519014..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.523254..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.538260..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.735998..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc docker[1970]: time="2016-01-07T13:34:44.766801..."
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exite...E
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, c
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Con
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) docker.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) docker.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed st
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'ex
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc sudo[1963]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc polkitd[392]: Unregistered Authentication Agent fo
janv. 07 13:35:24 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Director
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a commencé à démarrer.
janv. 07 13:35:24 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directori
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a terminé son démarrag
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a terminé son démarrage, avec l
lines 1695-1717/1717 (END)
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) docker.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) docker.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc sudo[1963]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
janv. 07 13:34:44 boblinux-pc polkitd[392]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1964:86659 (system bus name :1.41, obje
janv. 07 13:35:24 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a commencé à démarrer.
janv. 07 13:35:24 boblinux-pc systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
```

i tryed many things but i didn't find the solution, so thanks you guys if someone can help me, and sorry for my bad english, i'm not english =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, it was problem of manage users/groups,

i tryed with sudo to pull ubuntu with docker :

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
fcee8bcfe180: Pull complete 
4cdc0cbc1936: Pull complete 
d9e545b90db8: Pull complete 
c4bea91afef3: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:b53bb7b0d18842214ac7472c2a8801e8682c247d30f1ba4bab0083a2e2e091ea
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

and here i try to run it, and it works ! :

```
sudo docker run -it --name ubuntu ubuntu
pass [sudo] de boblinux :
root@3a99cdd1c522:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@3a99cdd1c522:/# exit
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem, but the above solution did not help. I had to re-install docker to get this running back. This issue I suspect is I had resized (memory scaled up) the instance where docker was installed.

Comment: Maybe, that's because the new instance has a different hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me

You need to remove cleanup old local repo. By using following command.

rm -rf /var/lib/docker